# vba excel: find out why a cell is automatically being cleared

Tags: excel, vba

There is a problem which I really need to resolve and need your help with.

There are a lot of different VBA Excel websites I have looked at to find an answer to my issue, but unfortunately I haven't been able to find the answer I am looking for.
I have around 200 modules in my "personal.xlsb" with a lot of code in it.
I also have a lot of forms and class modules used for several things.

**This is my issue:**
For some reason range("B4") from the Activesheet is being cleared automatically after running code.
In general it does not matter which code is being used, but after using code range B4 is being cleared.
For instance I could run code to copy the Activeworkbook.Fullname to the clipboard.

When I put in text or whatever in B4 after the cell was cleared before it is also automatically being cleared after that. I cannot put in any text in the cell without it being automatically cleared.

I tried to find out which code is being run to clear B4 e.g. with Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range) or with the Watch window, but it hasn't helped me so far unfortunately.

I haven't found specific code referring to B4 in all of my code, or referring to column 2 row 4.
I am more or less desperately looking for the code which is responsible for clearing range B4 automatically.

For example when I put this in the Direct window: `Range("B4").value = "B4 changed"` it is automatically removed. The  Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range) is too late to see why the cell was cleared and the watch window on B4 doesn't spot anything even though I thought it should. I have tried a lot of things already (understatement).

When I change this in the Direct window: `Application.Calculation = xlManual` then it does not clear B4 when I put in text, but after I put it back to xlAutomatic, B4 will be cleared anyways.
I also checked if using `Application.EnableEvents = False` is helping, but it does not change anything on automatically clearing B4. I also checked if some Public declarations would refer to B4 but they don't. Also there is no conditional formatting involved.

Please help me find out which code is being run automatically to clear B4, I would really appreciate this!!

Kind regards,

Richard

Comment: Is this behavior on **all** worksheets or one **one** ??

Comment: Protect cell B4 and run the code to get an error message. The message will contain hints where something is trying to clear B4.
https://www.excel-easy.com/examples/lock-cells.html

Comment: @Gary'sStudent only on the activesheet

Comment: @StureS Thank you for your proposal. Unfortunately it went into an infinite loop which I could not stop with Ctrl+Break, so I had to close Excel because it did not respond anymore.

Comment: Well, there you have it. Do you run VBA code in the workbook?

Comment: @StureS not in the workbook itself, but from "personal.xlsb".
Just to explain what I did: I changed the calculation to manual, put in text in B4, protected the cell, protected the worksheet and then changed the calculation to automatic and ran code. I opened a form and ran the below code and then it went into an infinite loop.

'Public Sub PasteToMergedCell()
   Dim objData As Object
   Application.ScreenUpdating = False
   On Error Resume Next
   Set objData = GetObject("New:{1C3B4210-F441-11CE-B9EA-00AA006B1A69}")
   With objData
      .GetFromClipboard
     '

Comment: 'Activecell.Value = .GetText
      Activecell.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Clean(Activecell.Value)
   End With
   With Selection
   .WrapText = False
   End With
   Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub'

Comment: Well, then I suggest you load the *personal.xlsb* and convert it to .xlsx (or .xlsm if it contains VBA code).
I'm unsure why you don't troubleshoot properly. If I had that code at hand I'd find the reason/bug immediately

Comment: @StureS the personal.xlsb is the workbook which contains all the modules with all the code. The VBA code I used is mentioned in my previous two comments.
I do not understand why converting the "personal.xlsb" workbook to xlsm would help me with the issue I am facing?

Comment: Maybe not but I'm old school. I set breakpoints in code and single step, evalutating values of variables and generally find the culprit in no time.

Comment: @Gary'sStudent Do you perhaps know of a way to find out which code is responsible for the automatic clearing of B4? Or can you point me in a certain direction? In general any code could trigger that code. My assumption is that a function or a Public declaration is creating the recalculation and the clearing of B4. I would really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

I would approach this step-wise.  First create a new standard module and include:

```
Public WhoAmI As String

Sub ev_on()
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub

Sub ev_off()
    Application.EnableEvents = False
End Sub
```

and in the worksheet code area:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim Be_4 As Range
    Set Be_4 = Range("B4")
    If Intersect(Target, Be_4) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    MsgBox WhoAmI
End Sub
```

1. Get to the point in your process where you know that **B4** will auto-clear if you try to manually enter a value in it.
2. Run `ev_off`
3. Verify that the worksheet is un-protected and **B4** is un-locked
4. Verify that **B4** is not subject to *Data Validation*
5. Attempt to put a value in **B4**
6. Note if the auto-clear occurs.

If the auto-clear **still** occurs, you have a problem that is beyond my ability.  If the auto-clear has been prevented you begin a very tedious process of updating your subs one-by-one to include at the top:

```
Sub anyroutine()
    WhoAmI = "anyroutine"
    ' more stuff
End Sub
```

So all suspect subs will record their names in the global string. Then run `ev_on` and try to detect the miscreant.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I just tried it. It didn't autoclear when the ev_off had run, but when I ran the ev_on it autocleared. I had not put the WhoAmI in all the modules because there are many (really). But I did get the messagebox 3 times with a "space", so it does detect the change. Strangely when I ran the ev_off again and put in text in B4 it still autocleared. Only when I add Application.Calculation = xlManual it does not autoclear. I will put the WhoAmI in all the modules starting with the "suspicious" and share the results when I am finished. Hopefully I will find the culprit.